# Webkit Image Modification Tool

Tags: html, css, webkit

Is there any image modification tool out there that will work on webkit?

Something like the one on this page
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/imagecropper/simple_crop.html

Except that when you interact, you interact with the image in a given space and the mask is fixed (i.e pinching the image, rotating the image etc)

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 0):

The [jQuery image crop plugin](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/jquery-image-crop-plugin-jcrop/) should work with Webkit and does cropping. I don't know of a free plugin that can do image rotation at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

WebKit supports html5 canvas and canvas supports image manipulation. You could make an app to do this. I recommend looking [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/canvas_tutorial)